# Form and Button disappearing after clicking anywhere on page in Bootstrap

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a search form with a submit button on my page. When you click anywhere on the page the form and button disappears. Only want button and form to disappear if I click submit button. Here is the form code.

```
<form class="pc-search-input" role="search" action="showsearchresults.asp">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="hidden" name="pageStyle" value="<%=bType%>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="resultCnt" value="<%=pcIntPreferredCountSearch%>">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keyword" placeholder="Search">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    </form>
```

I would like to disable for this particular form only.

Comment: What is causing it to disappear? Javascript? Magic?

Comment: @DerekS definitely magic

Comment: It was JavaScript.